# Ruby function always returns true in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, methods, sinatra

I expect this to be an oversight on my part, as I'm new to Ruby, Haml, and web-development in general.

I have a helper class called authorization helper:

```
helpers do
    def authorize!
        lang = "EN"
        redirect "/#{lang}/login" unless authorized?
    end

    def authorized?
        return false
    end
end
```

You'll probably notice `authorized?` explicitly returns false.

The problem is, `authorized?` always returns true. Looking at it:

```
get '/*/login' do
    haml :"#{params[:splat][0]}/login"
    "#{authorized?}"
end
```

when viewed in the web browser, it displays true.

Furthermore, it evaluates to true in the Haml file:

```
%body
    -if authorized?
        Authorized
    -else
        Not authorized
    .container
        .row
            =yield
```

Comment: I believe here is an additional method `:authorized?` which returns true.

Comment: Ah, that was it exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, there is an additional method `:authorized?` which returns true. At first, please check your source to presence of a method with the same name. Than you can use `:source_location` method to know where is the method is located, for example as follows:

```
method( :authorized? ).source_location
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to do:

```
get '/*/login' do
    haml :"#{params[:splat][0]}/login"
    authorized?
end
```

to call the method and return the truth value `false`.

`"#{authorized?}"`, being a string interpolation, is evaluated to the string `"false"`. Strings are always true in ruby.

To clarify, `"#{authorized?}"` is equivalent to `authorized?.to_s`, which returns `"false"` instead of `false`.

Comment: I was using "#{authorized?}" to view the result of the function in the browser. It actually displays true in the browser, not false, or "false", as you say it should.